# How to use jquery of cloudinary to display success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary

I am using cloudinary Upload widget to upload multiple image. I am success on uploading the images to cloudinary but I am not able to show success message after process is completed.I have used following javascript to upload multiple images.

```
 <script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {
        cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'shreeya', upload_preset: 'album_widget', tags: '{{ uploadTag }}'  },
            function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
    }, false);
</script>
```

In the documentation, these is given how to show success message after upload process is completed .The given code in documentation how to show success is given below

```
$(document).on('cloudinarywidgetsuccess', function(e, data)

 {
  console.log("Global success", e, data);
});
```

Now ,I need help how to use this jquery code to show message after image upload process is completed.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it mention the 'cloudinarywidgetsuccess' event?

Comment: On the current version of documentation it is missing .you can find on this link https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget_1. There is separate heading for this event Named as `cloudinarywidgetsuccess - Global success event binding`. But this version is already Deprecated

Answer (score 0):

According to the *documentation of cloudinary **in your question only***, you can use the following:

```
<!-- Just make the placeholder for message (anywhere on the necessary place in the document)-->
<!-- like -->
<span id="fileResponce"></span>
```

Then you can use the same event provided by cloudinary:

```
$(document).on('cloudinarywidgetsuccess', function(e, data) {
    $('#fileResponce').text('Files uploaded successfully..!'); //and append the message in the placeholder span
});
```

Comment: please could you see my below in answer, you can see what I have done to get success message . still I haven't received success message after image is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You've already got an event listener setup for when the files are uploaded.  That's this line:

```
function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) }
```

You just need to extend that to check what the `result` is

```
document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {
    cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ 
        cloud_name: 'shreeya', 
        upload_preset: 'album_widget', 
        tags: '{{ uploadTag }}'  
    },
    function(error, result) {       
        if (result && result.event === 'success') {
            console.log("Global success", result);
        }

        if (error) {
            console.log("Error", error);
        }
    }
    );
}, false);
```

See:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#cloudinary_createuploadwidget_options_resultcallback

`cloudinary.createUploadWidget(options, resultCallback)`

> `resultCallback` is an optional function called for event handling. The
>   callback method has the following signature `function(error, result)`
>   where `error` is either `null` if successful or an error message if there
>   was a failure, while `result` is a JSON object detailing the triggered
>   event.